# Issue using sed to replace line in file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a line in my file that I'm trying to replace using `sed -i` but have been running into problems.

The line is

> set feat_files(1) "/Users/lab/Desktop/1026/20170802151230_1"

and I want to change it to

> set feat_files(1) "/Users/lab/Desktop/1026/20170802151230_2"

So far I've tried the following with no luck:

`line_old="/Users/lab/Desktop/1026/20170802151230_1"`
`line_new="/Users/lab/Desktop/1026/20170802151230_2"`

`sed -i '' 's/feat_files(1) '$line_old'/feat_files(1) '$line_new'/' $file`

Comment: Change single quote into double quote. `sed -i "s|$line_old|$line_new|g" $file`

Comment: This is a duplicate — but I don't immediately have the question it's a duplicate of on hand.  Searching is required.  It's a standard `sed` problem.'

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

Is it not enough to?:

```
sed -i '' 's/20170802151230_1/20170802151230_2/'
```

Comment: It depends, but in general, no.  For the particular change shown in the question, yes, but the necessary change might not be as conveniently simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with single quote. Use double quotes when replacing with a shell variable.

```
$ sed "s|$line_old|$line_new|g" input_file 
set feat_files(1) "/Users/lab/Desktop/1026/20170802151230_2"
```

Comment: The problem isn't the single quotes because the question uses `'s/feat_files(1) '$line_old'/feat_files(1) '$line_new'/'` which terminates the single-quoted string before interpolating `$line_old` and `$line_new`.  The key change in your answer is the use of `|` instead of `/` for delimiting the sections of the `s///` command. I note that you've eliminated the `feat_files(1)` part of the context so your example could make unwanted changes, in theory.

Answer (score 0):

The slashes in the replacement text confuse `sed` about what's part of the `s///` command and what is pathname.  The fix is easy — use a different character to mark the parts of the substitute command:

```
sed "s%feat_files(1) $line_old%feat_files(1) $line_new%" $file
```

This uses a `%` in place of the `/`; you could use any character that doesn't appear in the file names.  Consider <kbd>Control-A</kbd> or another control character if you think `%` might appear some time.

You can even change the character marking the ends of a searching (matching) regex if need be:

```
sed "\\%feat_files(1) $line_old%,\\%feat_files(1) $line_new% { … }"
```

to match the lines between the patterns in `$line_old` and `$line_new`.

I use double quotes because of the variables.  An alternative is to do what the question started to do, and use single quotes, but you should still surround the variables in double quotes:

```
sed 's%feat_files(1) '"$line_old"'%feat_files(1) '"$line_new"'%' $file
```

The code in the question must be running on a Mac with the BSD `sed`.  The GNU `sed` variant doesn't like the empty argument after the `-i` option; you specify just `-i` with GNU `sed` to do in-situ replacement.  For portability, you need to use `-i.bak` with a non-empty suffix attached to the `-i` option — and you have to remove the backup.

Don't use the `-i` option (with either version of `sed`) until you've got the basics working.  It can wreck your original file if you aren't careful.  (Of course, you're probably working on a copy of the original while testing, but having to restore the file to a known state before each test is unnecessary work, in my book. It's much easier just to leave the file unchanged until you know the script will work.)